# calling database to check for errors in a web app

Tags: php, mysql, objective-c

I'm building a web app to check for errors in our mobile app that also has a web interface.  I'm having trouble calling the database through php. In the mobile app it is called in Objective C by:

```
-(BOOL)login:(NSString *)username password:(NSString *)password{

// Create new SBJSON parser object
NSString * passwordToServer = [self sha1:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"REMOVED FOR SECURITY", password]];
NSString * authToken = [self sha1:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", SECURESTRING, username, passwordToServer]];
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@%@", SERVERURL, @"api/login/", authToken]]];
// Get JSON as a NSString from NSData response
NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
if([json_string isEqual:@"ERROR"]){
    loggedIn = FALSE;
    return FALSE;
} else{
    //GET ALL CAMPAGNS
```

How would I call into this server using php if I have the serverurl, securestring and the passwordtoserver?

I've tried using this but it doesn't seem to work:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("mydatabaseurl", "securestring", "passwordtoserver") or die(mysql_error()); 
?>
```

Comment: don't use mysql_connect use PDO or mysqli and what is the error message? with regards the objective c i'm not sure if this would have an effect as i've never used it myself.

Comment: Warning: mysql_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Comment: Firstly what  have you checked your database location, username & password is correct

Answer (score -1):

I think the mobile app you're looking at is just a client side application which talks to a server application that actually connects to your database (judging from the login URL and authtoken). It also looks like you're writing a PHP server application, which means you need to know the MySQL database server information that your mobile app's server application is using.